# Unable to save Schema. An unexpected version is found in the URI: tcm:x-xxx-x-v0

Tags: web8, cme, schema

I'm updating an internal Schema by deleting a single field. Saving the Schema and the Content Manager throws an error:

> Unable to save schema. An unexpected version is found in the URI: tcm:3-115-8-v0.

I checked the specified URI (it's a Schema) defined in the error and its history but found no reference to the single field that I've deleted; there were no changes to the Schema fields. There isn't a version 0 either.

I've also checked the logs for the CM but found nothing which would indicate why this is occurring.

Does anyone have any idea why this error is occurring?

**Update**

This is a new installation of SDL Web 8.5.0

Comment: Can you please edit and to include add more information on the SDL version details or this happening after the upgrade or new installation?

Comment: Are you updating this Schema in the CME, or are you doing it via an API? `-v0` in the URI indicates this is the Checked Out version that you are working on.

Comment: It's checked in now and it's working as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the item is checked out somewhere. Maybe checked out by someone else. Check it in and try again.